# Play 2.5 How to convert from Scala Form to Java Form?

Tags: scala, playframework, play-authenticate

This is a bit of an odd situation because with the Play framework one stick to either Java or Scala. In my case, I want Scala but also want to build of top of the [play-authenticate](https://github.com/joscha/play-authenticate) project that is implemented as a Play Java plugin (and not Scala).

Attempting to migrate their usage sample to Scala and after doing most of the migration to Scala I bumped into the issue of having Scala `play.api.data.Form` types and need to pass to the play-authenticate framework Java's `play.data.Form` type. Therefore I need conversion between these two separate (no common abstraction or anything) classes.

I already checked the `play.core.j.JavaHelpers` implementation but there is nothing to convert between the two separate `Form` types. I could do it manually but it is a maintenance toll and was wondering if anyone has already bumped into this and how it was solved?

**UPDATE** I tried `PlayMagicForJava` as follows but there was no magic :X

```
import javax.inject.{Inject, Singleton}

import play.api.data.Forms._
import play.api.i18n.Messages
import play.api.mvc.RequestHeader

case class Signup(email: String, password: String, repeatPassword: String, username: String)

@Singleton
class SignupForm @Inject() (implicit val request: RequestHeader, messages: Messages) {
  import play.core.j.PlayMagicForJava._

  val Instance : play.data.Form[Signup] = play.api.data.Form {
    mapping(
      "email" -> email,
      "password" -> nonEmptyText(minLength = 5),
      "repeatPassword" -> nonEmptyText(minLength = 5),
      "username" -> nonEmptyText()
    )(Signup.apply)(Signup.unapply).
      verifying(messages("playauthenticate.password.signup.error.passwords_not_same"),
        data => data.password != null && !data.password.isEmpty && data.password.equals(data.repeatPassword))
  }
}
```

and the error:

```
[error] SignupForm.scala:16: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : play.api.data.Form[views.form.Signup]
[error]  required: play.data.Form[views.form.Signup]
[error]       val Instance : play.data.Form[Signup] = Form {
```

Comment: As far I know you have to use  ``` PlayMagicForJava```
Here the documentation: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/scala/index.html#play.core.j.PlayMagicForJava$
And convert all Fields manually and construct a new Scala form.

Comment: Is there a gist somewhere? sounds involved to do that ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very unfortunately the only way was to rewrite the affected Forms to Play Java Forms. The hybrid approach leads to issues in the views that expect Scala `play.api.data.Form` types and not Java `play.data.Form` types but the solution to support this hybrid approach was to import `PlayMagicForJava` static context into the affected views.